# Eigenspaces and maximality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**QUESTION:** Given that $V$ is a vector space. And $V=\bigoplus_i E_i(\lambda_i)$. Where $E_i(\lambda_i)$ are the eigenspaces of $V$. Is it true that given any $T$ invariant subspace $U$ of $V$ then $U$ must be contained in one of the eigenspaces?

Comment: What is an eigenspace of a vector space? I've heard of eigenspaces of operators. What is $T$? Should your post read: "Where $E_i(\lambda_i)$ are the eigenspaces of a linear operator $T:V\to V.$"?

Comment: Yes they are eigenspaces of an operators $T\in \mathcal{V}$

Comment: Okay, well, what is $\mathcal V$, then?

Comment: Whoops. $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Past comment had a typo.

Comment: Aha! Excellent. Assuming that $\mathcal L(V)$ indicates the space of linear operators $V\to V$, as I suspect, then my answer applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Assuming that $T$ is a linear operator $V\to V,$ observe that $V$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of itself, regardless of the eigenvalues of $T.$

Even if we insist on a *proper* $T$-invariant subspace, we can find a counterexample (if $V$ is of sufficiently large dimension). Consider $V=\Bbb R^3,$ $T(x,y,z)=\langle x,2y,3z\rangle,$ and $U=\bigl\{\langle x,y,0\rangle:x,y\in\Bbb R\bigr\}.$